# throw a football with turtle graphics

Tags: python, game-physics, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

School is out and I seen this problem on Chegg so I started it but now I'm stuck on a few things.
First, it says `sin` is undefined
Second, I kinda don't know what `Xi` and `Yi` is used for so I don't understand how to interpret them.
Third, I don't know how to make the line move

[image: assignment I'm trying]

my code

```
import random
import turtle
import math 
v = float(input("What's the Velcity you want throw: "))
A = float(input("The angle do you want to throw the ball: "))
t = 0
Vx = v * sin(A)
Vy = v * cos(A)
X = Xi + Vx * t
Y = Yi + Vy * t - g * t^2 / 2


class player_one:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, color = (0,0,0), size = 5, r=25):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.r = r


    def draw_player_one(self):
        turtle.colormode(255)
        turtle.pencolor(self.color)
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(self.x,self.y)
        turtle.pensize(self.size)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.circle(self.r)   #draws the circle
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(30)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.backward(50)
        turtle.left(60)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.backward(50)
        turtle.right(30)
        turtle.backward(30)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.backward(30)
        turtle.right(15)
        turtle.up()
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.left(20)
        turtle.backward(30)

class player_two:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, color = (0,0,0), size = 5, r=25):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.r = r


    def draw_player_two(self):
        turtle.colormode(255)
        turtle.pencolor(self.color)
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(self.x,self.y)
        turtle.pensize(self.size)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.circle(self.r)   #draws the circle
        turtle.right(95)
        turtle.up()
        turtle.backward(50)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.backward(50)
        turtle.right(30)
        turtle.backward(30)
        turtle.up()
        turtle.forward(30)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.left(60)
        turtle.backward(30)
        turtle.up()
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.backward(80)
        turtle.left(50)
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(50)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.backward(50)
        turtle.up()
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(20)
        turtle.down()
        turtle.backward(50)




class football:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, v=0, t=0, g = 9.8):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
        self.v = v
        self.t = t
        self.g = g




player_render = player_one(random.randint(-700,-500),random.randint(-500, -200))
player_render.draw_player_one()
player_render2 = player_two(random.randint(500,700),random.randint(200, 500))
player_render2.draw_player_two()
```

Comment: `sin` is undefined because it's a part of the `math` module. So just like `colormode` is a part of the `turtle` module and you need to do `turtle.colormode(...)` to use it, you need to do `math.sin(...)` to use the `sin()` function. Also remember that trigonometric functions take their input arguments in radians.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], focus your post to _just one question_, and condense your code down to a [mre] that reproduces _the specific problem_ you're asking about. According to asking guidelines, your title should summarize the problem you're asking about. [You should also not upload images of text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `Xi` and `Yi` are the initial x- and y-coordinates of the ball. It says so in the question.

Comment: And finally, the assignment doesn't ask you to make the line move. All you need to do is plot it. More details on what the shape will look like, and how to calculate it using the information you have are available at the [wikipedia page for projectile motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion)